# ¿cómo dividir (split) una cadena de caracteres en base a un delimitador?

Tags: string, delphi, split

Estoy tratando de encontrar una función Delphi para dividir una cadena de entrada en una matriz o lista de cadenas a base de un delimitador. He encontrado muchas cosas en Google, pero todas parecen tener algún problema o limitación y no he encontrado una que me satisfaga para trabajar con ella.

Sólo tengo que dividir una cadena como:
`'palabra:doc,txt,docx'` en una matriz basada en ':'.

El resultado sería:
`['palabra', 'doc,txt,docx']`.

¿Alguien tiene una función que realmente trabaje?

Gracias

Pregunta y respuesta original: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2625707/255257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar (en conjunto) las propiedades [`DelimitedText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings.DelimitedText), [`StrictDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings.StrictDelimiter) y [`Delimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Delimiter) de la clase `TStrings` y sus descendientes para dividir una cadena en base a un delimitador arbitrario, tal como lo requieres.

Básicamente la idea es configurar el Delimitador, en este caso `':'`, poner `StrictDelimiter` a `True` para evitar que tome los espacios y otros caracteres no imprimibles como delimitadores (si fuera el caso).

Dale una mirada a este ejemplo:

```
program Project28;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

procedure Split(Delimiter: Char; Str: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings) ;
begin
   ListOfStrings.Clear;
   ListOfStrings.Delimiter       := Delimiter;
   ListOfStrings.StrictDelimiter := True; // Requere D2006 o superior.
   ListOfStrings.DelimitedText   := Str;
end;


var
   OutPutList: TStringList;
begin
   OutPutList := TStringList.Create;
   try
     Split(':', 'word:doc,txt,docx', OutPutList) ;
     Writeln(OutPutList.Text);
     Readln;
   finally
     OutPutList.Free;
   end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Para Delphi 7 no funciona lo anterior, (y para contemplar tambien casos en que el separador no es un único caracter), para separar una cadena en dos valores yo tengo el siguiente procedimiento:

```
uses SysUtils;

procedure SepararEnDos(Texto: string; const Separador: string; var V1, V2: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  //Si no hay separador en la primera devuelve el texto
  V1 := Texto;
  V2 := '';
  i := Pos(Separador, Texto);
  if (i > 0) then
  begin
    V1 := Trim(Copy(Texto, 1, i - 1));
    if ((i + Length(Separador) - 1) < Length(Texto)) then
      V2 := Trim(Copy(Texto, i + Length(Separador), Length(Texto)));
   end;
end;
```

Para lo que preguntan se llamaría, por ejemplo, con:

```
SepararEnDos('palabra:doc,txt,docx', ':', V1, V2);
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien...

Comment: +1 por dar una respuesta actualizada :)